# Application not opening after long time

Tags: android, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an worklight application. I generated android environment for the project... In the android app, I am able to see the main screen on background, but there is a busy icon which continues for long time, and i am unable to click on the main page anywhere when i am running the app on emulator.  After some time, it says "Client init failed. Connection to the service is unavailable"

I am getting the following log warning

> Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I have these errors in the log

> SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
>
> SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) -
>
> response [http://9.124.23.225:8080/apps/services/api/RQMLight/android/heartbeat] success:

I am getting the following message on the url :

> /*-secure-
>   {"WL-Authentication-Failure":{"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"reason":"Login Failed"}}}*/

! Logs  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VppU1.png)

I am also getting the error

> CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the 
>   server was unsuccessful. 
>   URL=file:///data/data/com.RQMLight/files/www/default/RQMLight.html

and

> onMessage(onReceivedError,{"errorCode":-6,"url":"file:///data/data/com.RQMLight/files/www/default/RQMLight.html","description":"The
>   connection to the server was unsuccessful."})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding the following line in the main java class which extends WLDroidGap. Write this inside  onWLInitCompleted() method

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

Comment: Normally you shouldn't do anything like this but it could be that your network conditions @ work add some delays... in any case - good! Please mark this as Answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I have solved it by using the real IP address of the server in the WL app instead of using localhost:

1. When the emulator is running your app, press the Menu button.
2. Select to change your server URL
3. Remove "localhost" and use the IP address.
4. Accept and try again.

This fixed my problem.